# How does it work to use "Response.Redirect" from a Razor Web Page When I Haven't Instantiated "Response"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

My limited knowledge concerning programming entails that in order to use a non-static method, you need to first create an instance of the class. In order to use static methods, you simply use the Class name with the method name. I'm doing the WebPages tutorials for on asp.net and I came across the following code which confused me:

```
@{
    var title = "";
    var genre = "";
    var year = "";

    if(IsPost){
        title = Request.Form["title"];
        genre = Request.Form["genre"];
        year = Request.Form["year"];

        var db = Database.Open("WebPagesMovies");
        var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Movies (Title, Genre, Year) Values(@0, @1, @2)";
        db.Execute(insertCommand, title, genre, year);
        Response.Redirect("~/Movies");   
    }
}
```

I looked up the Redirect method of the Response class and it wasn't listed as static, which I'd assume to mean that it is an instance method. How am I able to use it without first creating an instance of the Response class?

Comment: `Response` isn't a class in this case, it's a property of your underlying `Page` class. It returns an instance of `HttpResponse` which is what you're interacting with (i.e. the class name is actually `HttpResponse` and `Response` is the name of the property you're getting the instance from).

Answer (score 3):

Razor is a view engine plugin for ASP.Net MVC.

It does a number of things for you, such as on the fly code generation for your page views.  What this means is that there is an underlying [WebViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) class attached to each of your pages which Razor automatically descends from and merges with the code you have in the `@{ ... }` sections.

This gives you access to several properties helpful for communicating with the browser such as [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.response%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), [IsPost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.ispost%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.request%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), etc.  I picked these three simply because they are in use in the code you posted.

So, for example, instead of writing code like `MyPage.Response.Write("test!");` you can simply refer to the `Response` property of your page class directly.  Exa: `Response.Write("test!");`

Razor is smart enough to know that `Response` is a property of the underlying class and uses it.

---

The `Response` property is an object of type `HttpResponse`.  The response object has everything you need to write data (html for example) back to the client (browser).

The `Request` property is an object of type `HttpRequest` which gives you access to information sent from the client to your server.  For example `Request.Form` is a collection of the html input control data (textboxes, radio, drop down lists...).

`IsPost` is a simple `boolean` which tells you if the page was a postback or the initial get.

Comment: Chris, wouldn't it simpler to say that the Razor engine generates a class from the view page, and that this class derives from WebViewPage, which has a `Response` member?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: probably, but the OP is struggling here so I tried to take the long way around.

Comment: IMHO I think the long way is too long. Just tell him there's code generation going on, and show that a derived class is generated, and that the base class has `Response`. Maybe I'll have time to do that tonight if you don't do it first.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I trimmed it up a bit.

Comment: Razor is not built on top of MVC. Razor was developed for the Web Pages framework, and the MVC team made use of it to create a View Engine.

Answer (score 2):

The Response instance is created automatically by the webpages framework.

Comment: So I only have to instantiate when I'm dealing with a Class that I've personally created? Classes in the .NET library don't need instantiating?

Comment: @user2154633 The first part is correct, the second part isn't quite right. Certain classes are created for you by the asp.net webpages (or MVC, or WebForms, etc). In general, the .NET base class library doesn't do anything for you; it just provides classes for you to use.

Comment: No, every object is an instantiated class. ASP.NET creates the instance of `HttpResponse` for you and exposes it via the `Response` property (like a global variable (warning: gross oversimplification)). You still need to instantiate things yourself if they're in .NET, like `System.String`.

Comment: So it isn't simply a matter of static vs instance methods? How can I tell if the class is going to be automatically instantiated by the framework?

Comment: You'll have to get to know the framework you are using. The docs on it should explain what variables you can use in your view code.

Comment: @Femaref: It's frustrating because every class, book, or tutorial I've taken teaches how to create classes and the difference between static and instance methods, but they never show how to use the .NET Class Library. I'm very confused at the moment...

Comment: The thing is though, what you are asking is not specific to the .net class library. You are using a view engine in asp.net, called razor, which does a lot of plumbing in the background. Maybe you should backtrack a bit and write something in just C# (like a console app) to get used to the concepts. When you are better with it, you can start again with something like asp.net.

Comment: @user2154633: A book can't "show you have to use the .NET Class Library". The Base Class Library is just a set of tools. How you use those tools is up to you, and each tool (i.e., class) is used in different ways. You need to learn to search for appropriate classes that address the problems you are solvinge, and read the MSDN docs to learn how to use those classes.

Comment: I've been slowly going through Head First C#. I have to create a website for one of my classes, so it can't be avoided. I figured WebPages was a more introductory model for web development.

Comment: @user: you're new to this. Stop "figuring". You're "figuring" wrong.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are using razor, which is a view engine. For each view, a new class is generated, which derives from a base class. This base class has certain instance properties and methods, like `Response`, allowing you to use them in your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect(@href("~/Movies"));
```